# GSAP frame per second(fps) changing onStart() and onComplete()

Tags: jquery, animation, gsap

I am working on a HTML application which runs in an embedded device. There is a GSAP animation using TweenLite. For performance improvement I would like to do some tweaks in the frame per second of the animation. For a smooth animation, I need a `fps(40)` and as soon as the animation is complete, I would like to change the fps to `fps(0)`.

```
TweenLite.to($(element), 0, {
    scale: 0.95,
    opacity: 0,
    onStart: function () {
        TweenLite.ticker.fps(40);
    },
    onComplete: function () {
        $(element).css("transform", "none");
        done();
        TweenLite.ticker.fps(0);
    }
});
```

But the animation is always taking fps(0). `onStart` `TweenLite.ticker.fps(40);` is not working. 
In stead of `onStart`, I also tried it as below.

```
TweenLite.ticker.fps(40);
TweenLite.to($(element), 0, {
    scale: 0.95,
    opacity: 0,
    onComplete: function () {
        $(element).css("transform", "none");
        done();
        TweenLite.ticker.fps(0);
    }
});
```

Anyone have some idea regarding this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: GSAP is already optimized and will power down when there are no animations. Setting fps to 0 isn't a good idea - that's like telling it to never refresh again. I'm confused about why you feel the need to alter things like this. requestAnimationFrame is a very cheap operation.

Comment: Thanks @Jack. My client suggested this and hence I need to do a performance analysis in the mentioned method.